# Google Play Services (login, logout, leaderboard, achievement): cannot make a static reference to the non-static method from the type BaseGameActivity

Tags: android, layout, static, google-play-games

I am making a game. There is a `MainActivity` with several layout over the mainscreen. One of the layout involves Google user login / logout / leaderboard / achievement.

The code are as follows:

### MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    public static MainActivity main;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        main=this;

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GameAdapter.StartGame();          
        ....
    }
```

The `GameAdapter` which then invoke `MainLayout` to inflates the different layout over the main screen.

### MainLayout.class

```
public class MainLayout 
{  
    public static double FloorY,Gravity,WalkSpeed;
    public static void Inicial() 
    {
        ....
        SoundAdapter.init();
        FrontLayout.init();
        ....        
    }
```

### FrontLayout.class   (extending BaseGameActivity so as for Google Game Services)

```
public class FrontLayout extends BaseGameActivity
{
    public static Urect LoginHolder;
    public static Uimage Btn_lb, Btn_achieve, Btn_login, Btn_logout;
    public static Uimage Info, info_intro;

    public static void init()
    {
        Holder = Urect.CreateHolder(true);
        LoginHolder=new Urect(0, 0, Screen.Width/2, Screen.Width/2);
        Holder.AddChild(LoginHolder);
        Btn_login   =new Uimage(0, 0,   Screen.Width/6.5,   Screen.Width/6.5,       Media.btn_login);
        Btn_logout  =new Uimage(0, 0,   Screen.Width/6.5,   Screen.Width/6.5,       Media.btn_logout);
        LoginHolder.AddChild(Btn_login);
        LoginHolder.AddChild(Btn_logout);


        Btn_login.addOnClickDownListner(new ClickDownListner() 
        {

            @Override
            public void OnClickDownDo(Urect curentRect, double X, double Y) 
            {
                 beginUserInitiatedSignIn();   ###1
            }
        });

        Btn_logout.addOnClickDownListner(new ClickDownListner() 
        {

            @Override
            public void OnClickDownDo(Urect curentRect, double X, double Y) 
            {
                signOut();      ###2
                Btn_login.setAlpha(0); // visible
                Btn_logout.setAlpha(255);  //gone
            }
        });

        Btn_lb.addOnClickDownListner(new ClickDownListner() 
        {   
            @Override
            public void OnClickDownDo(Urect curentRect, double X, double Y) 
            {
                if(isSignedIn())     ###3
                {
                    MainActivity.main.startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getApiClient(), MainActivity.main.getString(R.string.leaderboard_highest_mark)), 2);   ###4

                }
                else
                {
                    Utilities.custom_toast(MainActivity.main, "Not yet signed in", "gone", "short", "center");
                }
            }
        });

        Btn_achieve.addOnClickDownListner(new ClickDownListner() 
        {

            @Override
            public void OnClickDownDo(Urect curentRect, double X, double Y) 
            {
                if(isSignedIn())     ###3A
                {
                    MainActivity.main.startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(getApiClient()), 1);     ###4A
                }
                else
                {
                    Utilities.custom_toast(MainActivity.main, "Not yet signed in", "gone", "short", "center");
                }
            }
        });
}


    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() 
    {
        Btn_login.setAlpha(0);      // visible
        Btn_logout.setAlpha(255);   // gone
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() 
    {
        Btn_login.setAlpha(255);  // gone
        Btn_logout.setAlpha(0);   // visible        
    }
}
```

### Questions:

Referring to the locations marked in the above code:

```
###1: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method beginUserInitiatedSignIn() from the type BaseGameActivity

###2: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method signOut() from the type BaseGameActivity

###3, 3A: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method isSignedIn() from the type BaseGameActivity

###4, 4A: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApiClient() from the type BaseGameActivity
```

The error marked are basically the raised from the same error...but how could such be solved? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `init()` is a static function so you cannot call non-static functions from there.

Comment: so would there be any way out?